# Django: POST Pandas dataframe using API, and Pickle or how to "hello world" serializer and view for binary data within Django REST Framework

Tags: django, pandas, django-rest-framework, pickle

This is a question building upon [How to send a pandas dataframe using POST method and receive it in Hug/other REST API...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473693/how-to-send-a-pandas-dataframe-using-post-method-and-receive-it-in-hug-other-res)

- How do I send binary data (the pickled Pandas Dataframe) using Django REST API to a models.BinaryField?

Below are my tries, but cannot get it to work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2, 3]})

import pickle
pickled = pickle.dumps(df)

import base64
pickled_b64 = base64.b64encode(pickled)
```

Want to send the pickled_b64 object, by POST via API to destination (www.foreignserver.com)

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://www.foreignserver.com/api/DataFrame/', data = {'df_object':pickled_b64})
```

.
.

## On Server www.foreignserver.com

**using *for Django REST Framework v. 3.9.4***

***models.py***

```
class DataFrame(models.Model):
    df_object = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

***serializers.py***

```
class DataFrameSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataFrame
        fields = ('__all__')
```

***views.py***

```
class DataFrameView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DataFrame.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataFrameSerializer
```

## **Result:**

- ==> A post is created but with Null value, the framework does not save the data package / binary data.
  However, I am given a 201 response.

  [09/Sep/2019 13:23:53] "POST /api/DataFrame/ HTTP/1.1" 201 64

To check if it memoryview address actually is empty, I retrieved the presumed object and analysed it with:

```
print(list(object))
len(object)
```

both turned out as 0.

**After some digging around I found that:**

> "BinaryField are not supported by Django REST framework. You'll need to write a serializer field class and declare it in a mapping to make this work." ref: [Django Rest do not show postgresql binary field in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816305/django-rest-do-not-show-postgresql-binary-field-in-view)

Comment: Note that pickle is not that safe, a malicious file may be generated by a attacker, consider this fact for production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*After some work I am able to respond to my own question. Below, I make my own interpretations/analysis, but perhaps misunderstand what actually happens in some steps. Nevertheless, below works as intended and is a complete answer to the question.*

## 1. Given no native (model) support for BinaryField within DRF, first step is to construct your own field:

```
class MyBinaryField(serializers.Field):
    def to_internal_value(self, obj):
        return base64.b64decode(obj)
'''
to_internal_value is obj to database and it seems DRF 
sees the POST as a string (despite being encoded as bytes, 
therefore, by decode the string, you get to 
the underlying bytes data (pickle.dumps).   
'''

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return base64.b64encode(value)

'''
to_representation is the visual feedback, and in order 
for being able to see the byte data one need to decode it.   
'''
```

## 2. Once you got your new Field, you implement it into a Serializer,

## and define methods.

## Please note that `serializers.ModelSerializer` wont work,

## so you need to use `serializers.Serializer`

```
class DataFrameSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    serializer_field_mapping = (
        serializers.ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping.copy()
    )
    serializer_field_mapping[models.BinaryField] = MyBinaryField

    df_object = MyBinaryField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `DataFrame' instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return DataFrame.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing 'DataFrame' instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.df_object = validated_data.get('df_object', instance.df_object)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

## 3. Finally, you define your view

```
class DataFrameView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DataFrame.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataFrameSerializer
```

## 4. Then, you can access and POST data through the API

```
import pickle
import requests
import base64
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
pickbytes = pickle.dumps(df)
b64_pickbytes = base64.b64encode(pickbytes)

url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/DataFrame/'
payload = {'df_object':b64_pickbytes}
r = requests.post(url=url, data=payload)
```

## 5. To retreive the data and re-create the DataFrame

```
 >>> new = DataFrame.objects.first()
 >>> byt = new.df_object
 >>> s = pickle.loads(byt)
 >>> s
    a
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
```

Helpful posts and docs related to the question:

```
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/33432733/10778349
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624941/10778349
[3] https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview
[4] https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields
[5] https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your serializer look like? It's possible that the binary is being saved (the response is 200) but your serialization doesn't know how to stringify a binary field. Please confirm the binary is being stored by inspecting the row in the database directly.

Looks like drf cannot handle BinaryField ootb. See [How to use custom serializers fields in my HyeprlinkedModelSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608737/how-to-use-custom-serializers-fields-in-my-hyeprlinkedmodelserializer/46620401#46620401)

Try

```
# serializers.py
from django.db import models

class MyBinaryField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return base64.b64decode(obj)
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return base64.encodestring(data)

class DataFrameSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    serializer_field_mapping = (
        serializers.ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping.copy()
    )
    serializer_field_mapping[models.BinaryField] = MyBinaryField
    class Meta:
        model = DataFrame
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for your answer. I have tried various ways to see if it contains any value. I have seen I got a memory address allocated but when trying to refer to that address it seems to return nothing. I completed with this in my question above.

Comment: use a db gui like dbeaver to inspect the df_object column on the new record.

Comment: Did this check with DBeaver (thanks, tried to do the same with phpPgAdmin but wasn't as clear as with DBeaver), confirms the entry is empty, see screenshot above

Comment: Share your serializer and view. You can have a sanity check in your view by printing a string. Also what does adding `print('stringify binary', base64.b64decode(self.DfObj))` show?

Comment: I've included the serializer and view. Its a new area for me and a bit confusing. Perhaps I would need to write a Post view to get it to work? as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205039/post-to-django-rest-framework.

Comment: Why does your api respond with `"url": "http://www.foreignserver.com/api/DataFrame/17/",` that's not standard drf behavior. Try sticking to the defaults when starting out. There is https://devdocs.io/pandas~0.25/reference/api/pandas.dataframe.to_pickle and on your `DataFrameViewSet` add the method I'll add to my answer.